# Facet being displayed on Search Page, but not the Category Page in Hybris

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I have written the following impexes to index a property and also to use it as a facet. It is appearing as a facet on the Search Page, but not on the Category Page. Can someone please help?

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty;solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique=true];name[unique=true];type(code);sortableType(code);currency[default=false];localized[default=false];multiValue[default=false];facet[default=true];facetType(code);facetSort(code);priority;visible;useForSpellchecking[default=false];useForAutocomplete[default=false];fieldValueProvider;
;$solrIndexedType;xyzName;string;;;true;;true;Refine;Alpha;;true;;;xyzNameValueProvider;

INSERT_UPDATE SolrSearchQueryProperty; indexedProperty(name, solrIndexedType(identifier))[unique = true]; searchQueryTemplate(name, indexedType(identifier))[unique = true][default = DEFAULT:$solrIndexedType]; facet[default = true]; facetType(code);
;xyzName:$solrIndexedType;;true;Refine;
```

Comment: Do you have other facets on Category Page?

Comment: Yes, all other facets provided OOTB are being displayed. The one I have created is being displayed only on the Search Page

Comment: Maybe there are no products within the specific category fulfilling the condition for your facet?

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. It's resolved now. Thanks. Can you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68891305/changes-not-being-reflected-after-impex-import-when-done-through-java-code ?