# Changes not being reflected after impex import when done through Java code

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I've written impexes which use Java code. I ran them in HAC. They were imported successfully, but changes are not being reflected which were made through the code.
Can someone please tell what needs to be done in order to reflect those changes?
The impexes used are:

```
$contentCatalog=apparel-ukContentCatalog 
$contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=$contentCatalog:Staged] 
$picture = media(code,$contentCV)

INSERT_UPDATE BannerComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;&componentRef;urlLink;
;;myBannerComp;My Banner Component;myBannerComp;/;


UPDATE BannerComponent;uid[unique=true];$contentCV[unique=true];$picture[lang=en];headline[lang=en];content[lang=en];
#%xyzService = de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean("xyzService");
#%xyz=xyzService.findXyzByCode("D100");
;myBannerComp;
#%xyz.getPhoto();
#%xyz.getName();
#%xyz.getDescription();
```

The above impex loads successfully in HAC, but when I check in the backoffice, changes made through code are not found.

Comment: please add code reference and expectation

Comment: Added the code, please check. Thanks

Comment: I hope,you have selected the code enable execution during hac run

Comment: Yes, I did that

Comment: I selected Enable Code Execution while running the impex through HAC. The impex was imported successfully. But the changes were not being reflected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try below impex.

```
$contentCatalog=apparel-ukContentCatalog 
$contentCV=catalogVersion(CatalogVersion.catalog(Catalog.id[default=$contentCatalog]),CatalogVersion.version[default=Staged])[default=$contentCatalog:Staged] 
$picture = media(code,$contentCV)

INSERT_UPDATE BannerComponent;$contentCV[unique=true];uid[unique=true];name;&componentRef;urlLink;
;;myBannerComp;My Banner Component;myBannerComp;/;


UPDATE BannerComponent;uid[unique=true];$contentCV[unique=true];$picture[lang=en];headline[lang=en];content[lang=en];
"#% beforeEach: 

de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.<package>.xyzService service = de.hybris.platform.core.Registry.getApplicationContext().getBean(""xyzService"");;
try 
{
    <CustomModel> xyz=xyzService.findXyzByCode("D100");
    line.put(new Integer(3), xyz.getPhoto());
    line.put(new Integer(4), xyz.getName();
    line.put(new Integer(5), xyz.getDescription();
    
} 
catch (Exception ex) {}
";
;myBannerComp;
```